# How to import to a non package from a package in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, package, pytest

This is the app structure.

```
app/
  setup.py
  package/
    __init__.py
    file.py 
  tests/
   tests.py
  ...
```

I'm trying to import from `file.py` into `tests.py` but it's throwing `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

**Hence my question is how to import to a non-package from a package in python?**

Comment: Add an empty `conftest.py` in the `app` directory: `$ touch app/conftest.py` and import as usual: `from package import file`, `import package.file`, `from package.file import some_func` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in your `tests.py`

```
from ..package import file
```

Comment: Does not work. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [import_module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) from importlib in your tests.py:

```
from importlib import import_module

files = import_module("package.file")
```

Also available for python 2.7 as far as I have seen.

**EDIT:**
This assumes that the top level structure 'app' is a package. i.e. has an `__init__.py` file

Comment: No, it's not a package.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add the path to sys:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/folder/')
import file
```